# Show that no matter the value for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x) = x^{100} - ax^{97} + 5$ is not injective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Show that no matter the value for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^{100} - ax^{97} + 5$ is not injective.

I've tried using the contrarian principle , that is , Proof By Contradiction :
Assume there is some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f$ is injective. It follows that for any $x_1, x_2$, where $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ , it must follow that $x_1 = x_2$ : With that ,  I was hoping that I come to some contradiction, but it's not obvious at least for me.  Any help would be nice.

Comment: Start with some obvious choices, say $x_1=1$ and $x_2=-1$. For which $a$ does this work?

Comment: There are several ways to go about this, maybe it would be helpful if you explained what kind of tools you want / are supposed to use (continuity, differentiability, none of those etc.)

Comment: no differentiability, no continuity, just the textbook definition of the injectivity.

Comment: If $a\neq 0$, $f(0)=f(a^{1/3})=5$ (I mean, of course, $a^{1/3}=-\sqrt[3]{|a|}$ if $a<0$). If $a=0$, $f(1)=f(-1)=6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only the definition of injectivity, you will need to find two values $x_1 \neq x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. I would start by writing

$$
x^{100} - ax^{97} + 5 = x^{97}(x^3-a) + 5,
$$

and look at the term $x^{97}(x^3-a)$. If $a \neq 0$, can you find two distinct values such that this term is 0?

If $a = 0$, you can directly work with $x^{100} + 5$. Can you find two distinct values such that $x^{100} = 1$?

> If $a \neq 0$, you can check that $f(0) = f\left(a^{1/3}\right)$. If $a = 0$, then $f(1) = f(-1)$. So in any case, the function $f$ fails to be injective.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Because this polynomial has even degree, with positive leading coefficient, both its ends go up (i.e. $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty$). And polynomials are continuous.

Comment: This was also my first instinct, but note that OP commented that only the definition of injectivity should be used.

Answer (score 1):

We can see that $f(+\infty)=f(-\infty)$ ( these will tend to $+\infty$ ) because $x^{100}$ has EVEN POWER & Positive Co-Efficient.

Naturally , there is some $x$ value where the Polynomial function will have a global minimum value. There may be multiple $x$ values where the Polynomial function has local minimum values.

All $y$ values more than the global minimum must have multiple $x$ values.
In other words $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\cdots=\cdots$

Here is the Outline of the function , which is not accurate in terms of the $x$ & $y$ values , it just shows (1) that we get $+\infty$ to the left extreme & to the right extreme & (2) where we will get multiple $x$ values for a $y$ value :

[image: 100]

The Dashed Blue line is below the global minimum , hence there is no $x$ value.
The Solid Blue line is touching the global minimum , hence there is Single $x$ value.

The Dashed Green line is above the global minimum , hence there are atleast two $x$ value , though there are 4 $x$ values here.
The Solid Green line is far above the global minimum , hence there are Exactly two $x$ values here.

That is sufficient to show the claim we are interested in here.
We can always get $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\cdots=\cdots$

ADDENDUM :

The global minimum might occur either at $x=0$ or at $x=\sqrt[3]{a/100}$
The minimum $y$ value will be either $y=5$ or ${\sqrt[3]{a/100}^{100}}-a{\sqrt[3]{a/100}}^{97}+5$.

Either way , we must have multiple $x$ values for $y=6$ & for $y=20$ & for $y=48$.

There are no $x$ values for $y$ values less than the global minimum.